# Activity has leaked IntentReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send sms amd mail together. There are no issues with sending mail, but when i send sms I receive this Exception:

```
End has leaked IntentReceiver
Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Here is my code for sms method from https://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android:

```
public class End extends Activity {
    
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    public EditText Details;
    public String user;
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.end);
        Details = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.details);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        final String email=b.getString("keym");
        final String pno=b.getString("keys");

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                String detail=Details.getText().toString();
                Mail m = new Mail("abc@gmail.com", "sdfsa"); 
                String[] toArr = {email}; 
                m.setTo(toArr); 
                m.setFrom("asdasd11@gmail.com"); 
                m.setSubject("EMERGENCY");
                m.setBody(detail);
             
                try { 
                    // m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 
                    if(m.send()) { 
                    Toast.makeText(End.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    } else { 
                  Toast.makeText(End.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    } 
                } catch(Exception e) { 
                //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
                } 
              
                sendSMS(pno, detail);
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(End.this,Service.class);
                startActivity(intent);
               }   
            }
        );        
    
    } 

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
         String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
         String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
  
         PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
             new Intent(SENT), 0);
  
         PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
             new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
  
         //---when the SMS has been sent---
         registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
         {
             Context context;
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                 switch (getResultCode())
                 {
                     case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                 }
               

             }
         }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
  
         //---when the SMS has been delivered---
         registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
             Context context;
             @Override
            
             public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
             {
                 switch (getResultCode())
                 {
                     case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                     case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;                        
                 }
             
             }
         }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        
  
         SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
         sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);    
    
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Create a custom receiver like this

```
class deliverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {     
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
             switch (getResultCode())
             {
                 case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
                 case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;                        
             }

         }
}
```

and a sent reciever like this..

```
class sentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {     
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
             switch (getResultCode())
             {
                 case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
             }


         }
```

now in sendSMS method after this

```
 PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
         new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
```

put

```
registerReceiver(sentReceiver,SENT);
registerReceiver(deliverReceiver,DELIVERED);
```

Now override onpause and unregister for the receivers like this..

```
unregisterReceiver(sentReceiver);
unregisterReceiver(deliverReceiver);
```

Comment: just make following changes: use    registerReceiver( sendBroadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter(SENT)) and 
 registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever,new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

Comment: Hey, this might sound silly but. If I unregister a receiver once my app is closed, I wont be able to receive intents to that BroadcastReceiver right?? If so wouldnt that defeat the purpose?

Comment: @alexsummers Are you registering the `BroadcastReceiver` in an `Activity` or in a `Service`? If the former then you cannot receive the broadcasts after the end of the activity's lifecycle.

Comment: Im using a `BroadcastReceiver` to reveive `PushNotifications` through `Parse-SDK`. Its only being registered in the `Manifest`. It works fine, but I get an `leaked-IntentReceiver` in the Log

Comment: Is it wrong to call `registerReceiver` in `onStart` and `unregisterReceiver` in `onStop`?

Answer (score 19):

You should unregister the receivers in `onPause()` and register them in `onResume()`. This way, when Android destroys and recreates the activity for the configuration change, or for any reason you will still have receivers set up.

Comment: hey can u tell me how u do it...with respect to above program!!

Comment: Why register them in onResume() vs. onCreate()?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky because `onResume` and `onPause` will be called every time UI is shown and hidden respectively. You don't want to listen to broadcasts out of that.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Yes, a potential memory leak.

Comment: I exactly did this but still keep on throwing the error

Answer (score 2):

You have registered two broadcast receivers in your activity. In onDestroy of your activity, unregister both the receivers. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver).

Comment: This answer is not correct, cause onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called.