# Android: how to launch my app upon receiving a specific Broadcast?

Tags: android

I am trying to get my app automatically launched when the phone gets connected to wifi. Here's the code I am using to both set the Broadcast receiver and to specify that once the broadcast is received I want the "Connected" activity to be launched:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.package.Connected.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                }
            };
registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);
```

Unfortunately it's not working. The logcat says my activity has "leaked IntentReceiver".

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

**EDIT**: I also tried to register the receiver via the Manifest file. I added this code to the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.package.receiver">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And then this code to my main activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.package.Connected.class);
            context.startActivity(intent2);
        }
    };
```

But now my app crashes once the phone connects to wifi. Logcat says "RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver".

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: in 2nd case you need to make a seprate class extends BroadcastReceiver and give the package of that in  android:name="com.example.package.receiver" including class name

Comment: Thanks, working on it right now.

Comment: Here is a sample app showing a manifest-registered receiver: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnWiFiChange

Comment: App is still crashing. Now logcat says "unable to start receiver".

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks I'll check that. I am also sending you guys an email right now about consulting work :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get my app automatically launched when the phone gets connected to wifi.

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, using a `<receiver>` element, and have the receiver call `startActivity()` on the `Context` supplied in the `onReceive()` method.

Note that users may not appreciate your popping up an activity just because the device connected to WiFi.

Comment: I tried this, but getting a crash now. I pasted my code above if you can take a look. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

as Per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577566/android-leaked-intentreceiver-exception-is-being-thrown-even-though-i-call-unre) and [Activity has leaked IntentReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781769/activity-has-leaked-intentreceiver)

Unregister the Broadcast Receiver that you created in the onCreate()

In the onRestart() re-register a brand new Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: But I want this to work even when the app is paused or not running. Should I sill unregister the broadcast receiver?